# vimrc autocmd: not-equal Filetype in

Tags: vim

I can use autocmd to make my cmd to run if file of specific file type loaded. For example for python:

```
autocmd FileType python make me happy with python
```

But is there any way to make my cmd to run if loaded file is NOT of specific type? Something like:

```
autocmd FileType !python make me happy without python
```

example above doesn't work and `autocmd!` will remove autocmd.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- The easy way is to call a function and make your function check the filetype (and abort, if the filetype is python).
- An alternative approach is to set a flag for python filetypes and make you function check the flag.
- Use the `*` pattern and call your code only inside an if condition checking the filetype (something similar to this):
  `autocmd Filetype * if &ft!="python"|put your code here|endif`
- The hard way is to create a pattern, that doesn't match python. Something like this should do it:
   `:autocmd FileType [^p],[^p][^y],[^p][^y][^t],[^p][^y][^t][^h],[^p][^y][^t][^h][^o],[^p][^y][^t][^h][^o][^n] :put your code here`

(the last part is untested and should illustrate, why usually any of the other possibilities are used).

Comment: Thank you. I used the third option as the easiest way for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can make an `autocmd` which triggered by all (`*`) filetype, then call a function.

In the function, you can check the `ft` option (`&ft`) to decide what should be done for certain filetype. There you can do any matching logic with the value of `&ft`.